# Google dialogflow small talk issue

Tags: node.js, nlp, google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

i am developing chat bot application with google dialog flow. i am using node js client https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2 to access the data of my chat bot. i have enabled small talk from the dialog flow console and it works fine when i use it from the dialog flow web demo or the console it self

[image]

for the same chat application i have implemented a api by using dialogflow node js client.

```
 if (req.body.text) {
        query = req.body.text;
    }
    // Get the city and date from the request
    var request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: query,
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };
    // Send request and log result
    sessionClient
        .detectIntent(request)
        .then(responses => {
            console.log('Detected intent');
            const result = responses[0].queryResult;
            console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
            console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
            if (result.intent) {
                res.json({ "text": result.fulfillmentText });
            } else {
                res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': "No intent matched" });
                console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
```

there i dont get the result i want. instead it goes to a different intent

[image]

what i have done incorrectly here..

Comment: How do you set a ```sessionPath``` variable?

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov `sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);` sessionId is a random no for each individual user.

Comment: What is the output of ```console.log``` statements in your code?

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov i tried that now. but it goes to "No intent matched" part now. if a send something about a intent it gives me the correct answer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "sending something about a intent"?

Comment: @AzaTulepbergenov that mean if i ask something regarding a intent (for example what is the weather today) it gives the relevent answer i want. but when i  ask "How old are you" it does not work. instead the out come is no intent matched. but when i try the same scenario in dialogflow console it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries defined in Small Talk section of your Dialogflow agent will not have an associated intent. If there was a matching intent, then you shouldn't have really added that query into Small Talk. Therefore, since there is not matching intent, the Dialogflow Node library will return an unmatched intent.

Comment: oh okay. so how do i get the relevant answer i wanted

Comment: ah okay i got that if i remove the if condition it wil come.. i will come uo with some thing. thank you so much.